# I am going crazy [syntax error]

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I can't believe I am having this problem. I've been looking and looking but I can't see what is wrong. I hate this error message.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' poster_ip, message, posted, thread_id INTO posts ' at line 1



mysql_query("INSERT poster, poster_ip, message, posted, thread_id
                INTO posts
                VALUES (
    {$post_info['poster']}, 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."', 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($post_info['message'])."', 
    {$post_info['posted']}, 
    {$post_info['thread_id']}") or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Your SQL syntax is wrong](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp).

You should be using something similar to:

```
INSERT INTO posts (poster, poster_ip, message, posted, thread_id) VALUES (...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should look at the doc ;)
[Insert Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)

If you're going to put the column names you should put it after the table name.

Example:
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a good opportunity to practice some debugging techniques.  Try building the string you are passing to the function and assigning it to a variable, then echoing that variable to see what it is you are actually passing to the function.  You can learn a lot that way about why you are getting errors.  Also, it would help to know the data types of the columns you are inserting values into.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this code to show you why arrays are useful for query generation and less likely to make a syntax error if you need to add more fields in future.

```
$fields = array('poster, poster_ip, message, posted, thread_id'); // Our fields
$table = 'posts'; // Our table name
$values = array(
    $post_info['poster'], 
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 
    $post_info['message'], 
    $post_info['posted'], 
    $post_info['thread_id']
);
$values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $values); // Secure all inputs
// Generate query
$query = "INSERT INTO $table (" . implode(',', $fields) . ") VALUES ('" . implode("','", $values . "')";
// Run query
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('query error: ' . mysql_error());
```